How do see if an image has loaded?
Im making a carroussel component which can have a children prop. In this case im using images
`            <Carroussel counter='Foto' className={"room-carroussel"}>
                {extraImages.urls.map((url, index) => (
                    <img
                        key={index}
                        src={`images/${url}`}
                        alt={`Image ${index}`}
                    />))}
            </Carroussel>`

but how can i set some loading state if the images are being loaded. Currently the carroussel removes and adds the image with the correct index to the dom.
`
            <AnimatePresence mode="popLayout" initial={false} custom={direction}>
                <motion.div
                >
                    {React.Children.toArray(children)[pageIndex]}
                </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>`


How do i know if the image or anything else for that matter has been loaded?
Im looking around everywhere and I can only find the onload property, but im unsure how i would link that to my carroussel???

Odd spelling of carousel with your Carroussel  but maybe valid in your language.

didnt even know it was wrong, thanks!

Images have an onLoad event. You can use them to keep track of the number of images loaded.
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    let TOTAL_IMAGES = 10;
    if (count === TOTAL_IMAGES) setLoading(false);
}, [count])

if (loading) return <Preloader/>

return (
    <Carroussel counter='Foto' className={"room-carroussel"}>
        {extraImages.urls.map((url, index) => (
            <img
                key={index}
                src={`images/${url}`}
                alt={`Image ${index}`}
                onLoad={() => setCount(count + 1)}
            />
        ))}
    </Carroussel>
)

